# simplify a rewrite rule on nginx

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I would like to simplify those rewrite rules, don't know if this is possible, here is what I did :

```
rewrite ^/en/m/(.*)/$ /index.php?lang=en&cat=$1&platform=mobile last;
rewrite ^/en/(.*)/$   /index.php?lang=en&cat=$1 last;
rewrite ^/m/(.*)/$    /index.php?cat=$1&platform=mobile last;
rewrite ^/(.*)/$      /index.php?cat=$1 last;
```

it works but the number of rewrite rules is quite big..

The parameter /m/ (for mobile) is optional, is there a way to simplify that ? Any idea ?

Comment: The very first and simple idea is to move url parsing into PHP script.

Comment: thank you Alexey, you solved my problem!:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally pass a single parameter and I parse it using php, it works like a charm, thank you Alexey!:)